# evaluate $\int_{0}^{6} \int_{0}^{12-2y} \int_{0}^{4-\frac{2y}{3}-\frac{x}{3}} x dz dx dy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> $$\int_{0}^{6} \int_{0}^{12-2y} \int_{0}^{4-\frac{2y}{3}-\frac{x}{3}} x dz dx dy$$

1. I got from $$\frac{4}{3} \int_{0}^{6} \frac{-2(6-y)^3}{3} -y(6-y)^2+6(6-y)^2 dy$$

to $$\frac{4}{3}[\frac{(6-y)^4}{6}-\frac{(6-y)^4}{4}]$$

But I can not find the mistake why I get $-144$ and not $144$

2. is there a easier way to solve it, can I use substitution in the limit of integration?

Answer (score 2):

To start with, we have $\frac q6-\frac q4 = -\frac q{12}$.  This yields

$$\frac{4}{3}\left[\frac{(6-y)^4}{6}-\frac{(6-y)^4}{4}\right |_0^6=-\frac 19\left[(6-y)^4\right|_0^6\\
=-\frac 19(0)-\left(-\frac 19\right)6^4 = 144$$

Did you forget to change the sign when subtracting the evaluation at $0$?

(I think your solution method is just fine; the evaluation step either needs to be carefully written out for each term individually, or combined as I have done so that there is less chance of sign-change error...)